# Why is there a difference between "git worktree add" with checkout and "git checkout"?

Tags: git

Two commands that should, according to documentation, do the same thing, have different results, and I do not understand why nor the implication of the difference.

**The First Command**

```
git worktree add -d "c:\temp\junk\blah" 209134fc8f
```

Result:

```
c:\temp\junk\blah>git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**The Second Command**

```
git worktree add -d "c:\temp\junk\blah"
cd "c:\temp\junk\blah"
git checkout 209134fc8f
```

Result:

```
c:\temp\junk\blah>git status
HEAD detached at 209134fc8f
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I expected these two commands to give the same status result. They do not. So my questions:

**Why do these two commands not have the same status result?
Is there a meaningful difference between not being on any branch vs the HEAD being detached on a commit? Both seem to work the same for later commands. I am using "-d" specifically because I do not want to create a new branch for this temporary worktree.**

Comment: Note that adding the "--checkout" to the worktree command does not produce different results.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't expect (or rely) on the output of `git status` or any other porcelain commands. That said, I was unable to reproduce the issue, both manners resulted in `Not currently on any branch.`

Comment: @CervEd On Windows? I've replicated on a couple machines here.
git version 2.36.1.windows.1

Comment: Yes. `git version 2.38.1.windows.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do these two commands not have the same status result?

Because `git status` is too clever for its own good—or maybe for your good.

> Is there a meaningful difference between not being on any branch vs the HEAD being detached on a commit?

This depends on what you consider "meaningful".

There are two or three keys to understanding this answer:

1. Git has (optional) *reflogs* (which are on by default for your case).
2. Each added working tree has *its own HEAD*.
3. As mentioned, `git status` is clever, perhaps too clever.

We must expand on each of these to get where we're going.

#### Reflogs

To understand reflogs in Git, we must start with the idea of a "ref" or "reference".  These "refs" are the generalized term for branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and all sorts of other names.  Almost all of these refs—or all of these refs, depending on which part of which Git documentation you believe at any given moment—are spelled with full names that start with `refs/`.  For instance, the branch name `main` is really just short for `refs/heads/main`.  The `heads` part of this is what makes it a *branch* name: if it were `refs/tags/main`, it would be the *tag* name `main`.

(This means you can have branch and tag names that are identical, once shorn of their `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` prefixes.  Don't do that.  Git won't get them mixed up, but *you* will, especially because the rules for which name takes priority depend on which command you use.)

There's one very special name, which part of Git calls a *pseudo-ref*, and that's `HEAD` (written in all uppercase like this: lowercase sometimes works on some systems, but don't use it: it's a trap).  This is not the only pseudo-ref as there are also names like `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` and more, but unlike the other pseudo-refs, `HEAD` can have a reflog.

Each ref or pseudo-ref stores one (1) hash ID.  (This makes `FETCH_HEAD`, which stores more stuff in it, not really a pseudo-ref, although in Git's usual squirrelly fashion, you can *sometimes* use `FETCH_HEAD` as a pseudo-ref.  For historical reasons, Git is not always systematic and just does whatever seemed fine [*ad hoc*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc) at the time, and now Git is stuck that way forever, or at least until Git 3.0 or something.)

The one hash ID stored in a *branch* name like `main` is, by definition, the *last* commit "in" or "on" that branch.  Two or more names can identify the same commit; in this case, both branches contain exactly the same set of commits, since the set of commits "in" or "on" any one branch is determined by reading the branch name to find the *tip commit*, then working backwards through the commits themselves.  *No part of any commit* can ever be changed once the commit is made, so if names X and Y both select hash `a123456...`, and we work backwards from that commit, we'll always find the same commits.  (We can *add new commits* to the repository, but we cannot change or remove existing commits.  We can change the hash ID stored in any *branch name* at any time, but again, we cannot change or remove the existing commits.)

So far, that's just saying how things are, so now let's get to the purpose of the reflog.  **Whenever we store a *new* hash ID in some existing name, it might be nice to save the *old* hash ID somewhere, so that we can see which commit some branch had as its tip commit yesterday, or last week, or whatever.**  This is what a branch-name reflog does.

Given that refs in general appear under `refs/*` names, Git simply stores a reflog for each such ref (currently in files, in `.git/logs/refs/`, but that's an implementation detail: these entries are in effect database entries, and it might be more efficient to store them in a real database, someday.)  These *reflog entries* carry a date-and-time-stamp and a hash ID, plus a message and various bits of auxiliary data; and you can dump out the contents of any particular ref's log with `git reflog` or `git log -g` (these are internally the same, except that they have different default `--format`s).

Reflog entries thus tell you what hash ID *was* in some ref at some earlier point in time.  This is how `main@{yesterday}` or `main@{2.hours.ago}` works: Git checks in the reflog to see what value `main` stored 24 hours, or 2 hours, ago.  These entries do eventually expire, and at least right now, if you delete a name, its reflog entries also vanish, though there have been vague plans to keep the reflog entries around to be able to "un-delete" the name.

Besides having reflog entries for branch names, remote-tracking names, and even tag names—though ideally a tag name's hash ID never changes—Git has reflog entries for `HEAD`.  These are updated whenever Git updates `HEAD`, including when you switch branches.  Running `git reflog` with no arguments dumps out the `HEAD` reflog.  While deleting a branch name deletes the branch's reflog, the `HEAD` reflog may retain the hash IDs that were in that branch, if `HEAD` was *attached to* that branch.

#### Added work-trees, and what is and is not shared

When you add a working tree with `git worktree add`, you pick a branch name or commit hash ID that Git should check out, as in your example.  If you use or create a branch name, the added working tree uses the *same* `refs/heads/` names as the original working tree.  This is what leads to the "must be a name that is not checked out in any other working tree" restriction, though to describe this correctly I would have to go into more detail about the index.

One thing that is *not* shared is obvious once you think about it: since `HEAD` literally *holds* the *branch name*—that is, `.git/HEAD`, a plain file, holds the literal text `ref: refs/heads/master` (plus a newline) if the main working tree is "on" branch `master`—each added working tree needs to get *its own* `HEAD`, so that it can be on a different branch.  And that's just what happens here: instead of using `.git/HEAD`, each added working tree uses a different pseudo-ref (still spelled `HEAD` but not stored in `.git/HEAD`).

This is why you have to use all-caps for `HEAD`, even on Windows and macOS systems: in the added working tree, if you type in `head` in lowercase, Git does not consider that a match to `HEAD` (uppercase) and therefore *doesn't* use the per-working-tree `HEAD` that's stored somewhere else.  Instead, Git tries to open the file `.git/head`, which—because of case-insensitive file systems—opens `.git/HEAD` instead and Git thinks you mean whatever commit is in the *main* working tree, rather than whatever commit is in the added working tree.  So if you don't like typing out `HEAD` in all caps, consider using `@`, which is a one-character synonym that *does* work correctly, even in added working trees.

Now, with all that in mind, remember our reflogs.  There's a reflog for `HEAD`, so for added working trees to work *right*, there must be a *separate* reflog for each added working tree `HEAD`.  And in fact there is.

(As alluded to above, there's also a separate *index* or *staging area* for each added working tree.  Certain pseudo-refs, such as those for bisection, are extended this same way.  Basically everything that "ought to be" per-worktree *is* per-worktree.  When it isn't handled consistently like this, that's a bug.  There were many such bugs in the early versions of `git worktree`, first introduced in Git 2.5.  One particularly bad one was fixed in 2.15, and a few more in 2.17.)

We're finally ready to address your original question.

#### `git status` and detached HEADs

The first output line from `git status` is normally `On branch branch`, at least when you *are* on some branch.  But you can be in "detached HEAD" mode, when you're on some specific commit, rather than being on some branch.  In early versions of Git, when you *are* in detached-HEAD mode, `git status` just tells you that you're not on any branch.  Similarly, `git branch` would say `HEAD detached at hash`.

At some point (pre-Git-2.4), `git status` got taught some extra cleverness, to dig through the reflogs a bit and try to figure out if you were still "on" the commit that some earlier *branch name* selected, and say so:

```
HEAD detached at <hash>
```

or, if you'd moved `HEAD` since then by checking out some earlier commit or using `git reset` or whatever:

```
HEAD detached from <hash>
```

[In Git 2.4, `git branch` got taught the same trick.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/63bba4fdd86d80ef061c449daa97a981a9be0792/Documentation/RelNotes/2.4.0.txt#L28-L37)  And that's more or less where things stand today, aside from a lot of minor tweaking.

When you see "not currently on any branch", this means that:

- `HEAD` is detached, and
- there's *nothing* in the `HEAD` reflog to indicate an earlier commit or branch, so no way to pick `at` vs `from`.

When you see `at` or `from`, there's something in the `HEAD` reflog, and if there's an appropriate *branch name* you will get the name, otherwise you will get the hash ID.

Comment: Thank you. Would you consider the current difference in behavior to be a bug to be filed or just behavior that is-what-it-is in git? The fact that "git status" ever fails to give me a commit hash seems really bad since I have no other way of navigating. Something like "If you did branch now, you'd be on commit XXXX."

Comment: I'm not a fan of it myself, but I don't think the Git folks consider it a bug. Still, you might report it to the Git mailing list (provide the reproducer here) and see if you can get buy-in from one of the main Git contributors. Given that you're working with orphaned branches, *I'd* call it a bug-ette at least, here.